# How to create category for group to give permission to show all projects if them in project team?

Tags: project-server

how to create a category for a group in project server 2013?
and this category gives them permission to show all projects if them in a project team, to show data only and cannot delete this project.

Comment: what's your issue ? are you have permission issue or you need to configure category settings ?

Comment: i need to configure category settings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a category you should enabled Project Server Permission Mode. For more details check [sharepoint permission mode vs project server permission mode](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/23/sharepoint-permission-mode-vs-project-server-permission-mode-in-project-server-2013/)

Once the Project Server Permission Mode is enabled you should see the `Security` section within `PWA Settings`. For more details check [THE PWA SETTINGS OPTION IS MISSING](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/02/23/sharepoint-permission-mode-vs-project-server-permission-mode-in-project-server-2013/)

**To create a category:**

- Click on category within security section and click add.

**To configure your category to show only projects in case the current user is a resource in your project team**

- In Category , Project section check

  - Only include the selected projects:
  - The User is on that project's Project Team.

[image]

**Avoid deleteing project permission**

- Open your group that you have set this category to it.
- Then select your category at `Selected Categories` section
- And `allow` and `deny` the required permissions as you need!

[image]